# Best way to copy multi module project in maven

Tags: maven-2, maven

I have a maven project in which I would like to unpack all the child modules of a mutli module project. Does anyone know if the best way to approach this? There are over 100 modules in this project and I'm trying to avoid having to copy all this information somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to create a pom.xml file that has all the projects as dependencies.

1. If there is one submodule that has
   all other submodules as
   dependencies, then you are in luck, just add a dependency to that submodule.
2. If not, you will have to write a script or program that gathers the groupIds, artifactIds, versions (and packagings) of all the submodules. And creates a pom.xml with all of them as dependencies.

Then, in this project, you can use [`dependency:unpack-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) to unpack the projects:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
     <execution>
        <id>unpack-projects</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <includeGroupIds>com.basegroupId*</includeGroupIds>
        </configuration>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

(Set includeGroupIds to a pattern that matches all submodule groupIds)

Now you just have to call

```
mvn generate-sources
```

(or any other phase you configure in the execution)

Comment: Thanks, the system I am working on needs to use the module list from the pom as the source of data, my intent is to create a system so that we don't have to enter data in two places anytime we want to add or remove a module. Worst case I can read the pom myself and then resolve and copy the files manually, but I was hoping that Maven had something baked in to do this.

Comment: @BillMan no, by design, a parent project has no access to the sub module projects, so you have to reference all bottom nodes to get the full tree.